# Requests Update Browser

Tags: python, python-2.7

Sometimes when i try to get html code from a website with this code

```
import requests
url = "https://sit2play.com"
response = requests.get(url)
print response.content
```

i get this response

```
<h3 class="ielte9">
The browser you're using is not supported. Please use a different browser like <a href="http://www.chrome.com">Chrome</a> or <a href="http://www.firefox.com">Firefox</a>.
```

How can i avoid this, and get the real page content?

Comment: You need a better [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string. That site thinks you're using an Internet Explorer version <= 9. No wonder it's complaining! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add your user agent to the header of the request with

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

You can get your user agent from many websites like [this](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/).

### Edit

If the solution above doesn't work for you, which might be because you are using an old version of `requests`, try this one:

```
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update({
         'User-Agent': 'YOUR USER AGENT',
    })

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Try this user agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36`. Does it work?

Comment: Still getting same error,here is the code i am currently using
https://pastebin.com/gnDdaa8L

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158765/discussion-between-tobias-moller-and-ammarx).